# wanted to add java.util library to the build.sbt file

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using a base64 function from java.util library and im registering it in a spark UDF and trying to use in Spark-Sql

```
spark.udf.register("encodeBase64", (processname: String) => ( Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(processname.getBytes())))
```

however I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Base64` error whenevet I build the fat jar and run it in my spark cluster.

I wanted to add the java.util.base64 function to build.sbt ad proceed. Please let me know how to add the same to build.sbt.

> 18/06/21 23:49:47 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, ma2-gbit-ldn5006.corp.apple.com, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Base64

Comment: Which version of java is in your cluster and  spark ? Base64 is supported only in java 8

Comment: Thanks @maxmithun what is the alternative function if I use < java 8

Comment: Try using the base64 from the Apache common http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.7/apidocs/index.html